# MiniMax chess algoritm returns bad moves

Tags: java, chess, minimax

I'm having problems with my implementation of the MiniMax algoritm for my chess game. Most parts of it seems to work, but it either never makes the good moves or something is wrong with the evaluation (score based of both players active pieces) of them. 
For example if I set up check (fool's mate for example) the ai does something random instead of killing the king. I really can't pin out what I'm doing wrong.

The class that evaluates the board, StandardBoardEvaluator, seems to work after some testing, so the problem is most likely somewhere within the MiniMax implementation. The game is made up from a class Board, which has and 2D array with 8x8 objects of my own class Square, which in itself has a reference to an Piece (that can be null, or any of the typical chess pieces). 
In the algoritm i constantly makes new Board instances as going down the searchthree, which is why i made these "deep clone" constructors in Board and Square, so that does not seem to be the problem. Like this:

```java
public Board(Board originalBoard) {
        this.turnIsWhite = originalBoard.getTurnIsWhite();
        winner = null;
        squares = new Square[8][8];

        for (int rank=0; rank<squares.length; rank++) {
            for(int file=0; file<squares[rank].length; file++) {
                squares[rank][file] = new Square(originalBoard.getSquare(posStringFromFileRank(rank, file)));
            }
        }
    }
```

AND

```java
public Square(Square originalSquare) {
        this.pos = new String(originalSquare.getPos());
        this.piece = originalSquare.getPiece();
    }
```

I have an typical command class, MovePiece, for moving pieces. This uses another class, MoveCheck, to check if the move command is legal. MovePiece returns a boolean representing if the move is legal. Both these classes have been heavily tested and are working, so I don't think the problem is within these classes.

Here is the algoritm:

```java
public class MiniMax implements MoveStrategy{
    BoardEveluator bV;
    MoveGenerator mGen;
    int depth;

    public MiniMax(int depth){
        bV = new StandardBoardEvaluator();
        mGen = new MoveGenerator();
        this.depth = depth;
    }

    @Override
    public MovePiece execute(Board board) {
        MovePiece bestMove = null;
        int lowestValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int highestValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int currentValue = 0;

        String color = (board.getTurnIsWhite() ? "white" : "black");
        System.out.println(color + " is evaluation best move with MiniMax depth " + depth);
        List<MovePiece> allPossibleMoves = mGen.getLegalMoves(board, board.getTurnIsWhite());

        for (MovePiece mp : allPossibleMoves){
            Board tempBoard = new Board(board);
            mp.setBoard(tempBoard);
            if (mp.execute()){
                currentValue = tempBoard.getTurnIsWhite() ? min(tempBoard, depth -1) : max(tempBoard, depth -1);
                if (board.getTurnIsWhite() && currentValue >= highestValue){
                    highestValue = currentValue;
                    bestMove = mp;
                }
                else if (!board.getTurnIsWhite() && currentValue <= lowestValue){
                    lowestValue = currentValue;
                    bestMove = mp;
                }
                mp.unexecute();
            }
        }
        return bestMove;
    }



    int min (Board board, int depth){
        if (depth == 0 || board.getWinner() != null){
            return bV.eveluate(board);
        }
        int lowestValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        List<MovePiece> legalMoves = mGen.getLegalMoves(board, board.getTurnIsWhite());
        for (MovePiece mp : legalMoves){
            Board tempBoard = new Board(board);
            mp.setBoard(tempBoard);
            if (mp.execute()){
                int currentValue = max(tempBoard, depth - 1);
                if (currentValue <= lowestValue){
                    lowestValue = currentValue;
                }
                mp.unexecute();
            }

        }
        return lowestValue;
    }
    int max (Board board, int depth){
        if (depth == 0 || board.getWinner() != null){
            return bV.eveluate(board);
        }
        int highestValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        List<MovePiece> legalMoves = mGen.getLegalMoves(board, board.getTurnIsWhite());
        for (MovePiece mp : legalMoves){
            Board tempBoard = new Board(board);
            mp.setBoard(tempBoard);
            if (mp.execute()){
                int currentValue = min(tempBoard, depth - 1);
                if (currentValue >= highestValue){
                    highestValue = currentValue;
                }
                mp.unexecute();
            }
        }
        return highestValue;
    }
```

And the evalutor class

```java
public class StandardBoardEvaluator implements BoardEveluator {
    private int scorePlayer(Board board, boolean isWhite){
        return pieceValue(board, isWhite) + mobolity(isWhite, board);
    }
    private int mobolity(boolean isWhite, Board board){
        return (int) (board.getActiveSquares(isWhite).size() * 1.5);
    }
    private static int pieceValue(Board board, boolean isWhite){
        int piceValueScore = 0;
        for (Square square : board.getActiveSquares(isWhite)){
            piceValueScore += square.getPiece().getPieceValue();
        }
        return piceValueScore;
    }
    @Override
    public int eveluate(Board board) {
        return scorePlayer(board, true) - scorePlayer(board, false);
    }
}
```

Here is the MovePiece class:

```java
private Square from;
    private Square to;
    private Board board;
    private MoveCheck mCheck;
    private RulesCheck rCheck;
    private boolean done = false;
    private Piece killed;

    public MovePiece(Board board, String from, String to) {
        this.board = board;
        this.from = board.getSquare(from);
        this.to = board.getSquare(to);
        mCheck = new MoveCheck();
    }
    public MovePiece(Board board, Square from, Square to) {
        this.board = board;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        mCheck = new MoveCheck();
        rCheck = new RulesCheck(board);
    }
    public void setBoard(Board board) {
        this.board = board;
    }
    public Board getBoard() {
        return board;
    }

    public Square getFrom() {
        return from;
    }
    public Square getTo() {
        return to;
    }
    public void setFrom(Square from) {
        this.from = from;
    }
    public void setTo(Square to) {
        this.to = to;
    }
    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = board.getSquare(from);
    }
    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = board.getSquare(to);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean execute() {
        rCheck = new RulesCheck(board);
        if (done) {
            board.movePiece(from, to);
            return true;
        }
        else if (mCheck.isLegal(board, from, to)){
            if (to.getPiece() != null) {
                killed = to.getPiece();
                rCheck.winCheck(killed);
            }
            board.setGameOutput("Moved " + from.pieceToString() + " at " + from.getPos() + " - to " + to.getPos() + "(" + to.pieceToString() + ")");
            board.movePiece(from, to);
            rCheck.checkPromotion(to);
            done = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void unexecute() {
        if (to.getPiece().getClass() == Pawn.class)
            ((Pawn) to.getPiece()).decreaseMoves();
        board.movePiece(to, from);
        if (killed != null) {
            to.setPiece(killed);
        }

    }
```

The MoveCheck class merely looks if the move is legal for the piece (path is clear, target is an enemy or empty and so on), don't think it's relevant for my problem since the code is tested and works.

The piece value is declared as an int in the subclasses (all the types of pieces) of the abstract class Piece. 100 points for a pawn, 300 for bishop and knight, 500 for rook, 900 for queen and 10 000 for the king.

If anyone could help me figure out the problem i would be eternally grateful! Please let me know if you need to se some other code i haven't showed.

Comment: did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not, and i got tired of i so i switched algoritms all together. I might look back at it at another time, but for now i just can't be bothered.
Thanks for the help though! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared the `MovePiece` implementation neither the main game loop, but I indentified two possible problems inside `MiniMax.execute` method:

```
currentValue = tempBoard.getTurnIsWhite() ? min(tempBoard, depth -1) : max(tempBoard, depth -1)
```

According to the above code, you are assuming that the MinMax player will always be black, as it evaluates `min` for white and `max` for black. For a generic algorithm this is a wrong assumption, don't know if it works for you though.

Second thing is after calling `mp.execute()` and assigning `bestMove = mp` you call `mp.unexecute()`, so effectively call `bestMove.unexecute()` since the variables point to the same object.

Please consider the suggestions above and if it does not fix the problem, share the abovementioned implementation pieces.

Comment: Thanks for the input!

I'm pretty sure that the currentValue line is correct, since later in the execute method I deal with if a high value or low value is wanted.

```Java
if (board.getTurnIsWhite() && currentValue >= highestValue){
                    highestValue = currentValue;
                    bestMove = mp;
                }
                else if (!board.getTurnIsWhite() && currentValue <= lowestValue){
                    lowestValue = currentValue;
                    bestMove = mp;
                }
```

Comment: Also the unexecute is not a problem, since I still store the from and to squares in the MovePiece object. I just call it again outside the MiniMax class when the execute method returns it. Of course you can not know this, so I will share the MovePiece class in my original post!

Comment: Ok, how I see it step by step is:
1) I want to see the best move for player X
2) I call the `MiniMax.execute` method creates for me a root node with the current board state (I am always a starting player in this root node)
3) From the root node I take **always max** value of the children nodes as my prefered move
4) To calculate value of the children nodes from root I need to go to each node and take **min** value of its children. 
5) This leeds me to descending further (until the leaf or maxDepth is reached) but remembering to take min/max accordingly.

Comment: Right now you calculate either min or max depending on a player color, ending up calculating **min** if the current player (in the root node) is white. Which basicaly makes him choose always the worst move possible.